# Apache Beam word count example fails with Spark Runner locally

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-beam

I have been trying to play with Apache Beam and as a part of my initial testing, I have been trying to get the word count example running. I have been trying out the MinimalWordCount example provided by Beam. The code is as follows:

```
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply(TextIO.read().from("file:///tmp/shakespeare.txt"))
            .apply("ExtractWords", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    for (String word : c.element().split(ExampleUtils.TOKENIZER_PATTERN)) {
                        if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                            c.output(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }))
            .apply(Count.<String>perElement())

            .apply("FormatResults", MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<KV<String, Long>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(KV<String, Long> input) {
                    return input.getKey() + ": " + input.getValue();
                }
            }))

            .apply(TextIO.write().to("file:///tmp/wordcounts/"));

    // Run the pipeline.
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

The idea is to run it locally with a spark-submit. Following is my spark-submit command:

> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master local[2] --class test.beam.example.MyWordCount /local/playground-1.0.0-shaded.jar --runner=SparkRunner --sparkMaster=local[2]

However, it keeps on failing with a NullPointerException at the following function:

> TextIO.write().to("file:///tmp/wordcounts/")

Following is the stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchNewResource(FileSystems.java:                                                            544)
>
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(FileBasedSink.java:213)
>
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$TypedWrite.to(TextIO.java:679)
>
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$Write.to(TextIO.java:997)

The exact same code runs when I run it with files on HDFS. So basically replacing

> hdfs:// instead of file:///

Do I have to do something more here to indicate beam to look for the files in my local file system?